# Saved Games API or Drive API for Android?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I need to save some game information which can be accessed later on the current device or on a different device.

**Should I really use Google Saved Games API over Google Drive API ?**

My thoughts: Google Saved Games API requireS Google Drive API as a prerequisite, e.g. when setting up the client. scores, achievements, and leaderboards are separate to the Saved Games API, so I can still have those without using Saved Games API.

So rather than having to deal with Snapshots, and Google Saved Games work flow, I could just access Drive API.

Maybe the only benefit might be Google Saved Games conflict resolution functions. Maybe there is conflict resolution for Drive.

UPDATE

Having done some more reading up on this topic the benefits of conflict resolution and the delayed upload when internet connections are unavailable make it worthwhile using Saved Games API over Drive.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHc2RBZs5T0) gives details of the Saved Games API, and my thoughts are now that Saved Games would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

**From Android version**: `6.0 (API 23)` onward this can easily be achieved as by default Android performs an Auto backup of files. ie Files of the type:

- Shared preferences files.
- Files in the directory returned by `getFilesDir()`.
- Files in the directory returned by `getDatabasePath(String)`, which also includes files created with the SQLiteOpenHelper class.
- Files in directories created with `getDir(String, int)`.
- Files on external storage in the directory returned by `getExternalFilesDir(String)`.

Now you can turn this feature on or off by changing the value here in `Manifest` file:

```
<application ...
android:allowBackup="true">
```

This keeps a backup in the users Google Drive, and the space is limited to `25MB` and that space is not counted against the user's space quota.

More information regarding this is available here:

- [Auto Backup for Apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html)

More information regarding including and excluding various files from backing up is provided here:

- [Android Auto backup for Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXacyy0HSW0)

So from API `23` onward you can save the game related info in any of the aforementioned files and not worry about retrieving it later.

Comment: This is really interesting - I did not know about this. However, an app has no control over scheduling, so is not "real time" enough for a game, e.g. suppose you run the same game app on two different devices, which creates data conflicts within a few minutes. The auto backup will not be enough to cope with this.

Comment: Hmmm... not so sure if I can't initiate my own backup now. In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXacyy0HSW0) Matthew says that we have no control over scheduling, but at the end he says you can initiate a backup/restore...

Comment: Hmm, I exactly knew this wouldn't suffice for gaming as you need minute accuracy, But I did answer it anyway so that at least someone from future may find it useful. How about Firebase real time DB for the purpose? It has offline storage as well as syncing

Comment: No, we do not have control in auto backup ,as it uses jobscheduler api,

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was very interesting ! I think I'm going to go with Google Saved Games API because it works from Android 2.3 upwards, helps to resolve conflicts, stores data for later upload if network is unavailable, and is much easier to implement after I found the video which I linked to in my question update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: :) . Good luck!